# highcharts unresponsibe graphics on Amazon Linux server

Tags: highcharts

Installed Highstock 8.0.0 on an Amazon Linux server: Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)
Installed and execute Apache version:
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 ()
Server built:   Oct 22 2019 22:59:04

Uploaded the highstock.zip and uncompressed it on /var/www/html

Installed node.js (v12.13.1) and set a test on port 3000.
I am able to browse it usnig my workstation Chrome v79.

Now when I test the index.htm provided by the highstock.zip, I get the browser displaying the
several graphics links on the menu page. I choose the first link (General -> "Stock chart with GUI")
nothinmg is displayed. Chose the second link (General -> "Single line series"), also nothing.
Then I switch and went to the end of the menu and teste the link "Flags and Indicators" -> "Flags shapes and colors"  and it works just fine. Go up, the next link above "Flags placement", and it also works.
and thats abou it. All other links on main page just freeze and show a blank page.

Now thew only thing I could notice is that the js associated to the links that worked has just 3 js attachments:

```
<script src="../../code/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Any adition to such list, which happens to all index.htm refered on the maisn menu page failed.
for instance if I try the link General ->  "Single line series", and open its index.htm (..//examples/basic-line/index.htm) I notice it refers to the same 3 js as the above one plus
export-data.js:

```
<script src="../../code/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```

Thats about it. Any clue ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! There isn't enough information for someone to help. You need a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). People will not know how your site is supposed to work.

Comment: In parallel to highcharts support I found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Using Chrome development tool I trace the error message:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.highcharts.com/.../aapl-ohlcv.json' from origin 'http://xxx.yyy.zzz.www' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Installed Chrome extension "Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin". Toggle it ON and graphics were displayed.

In parallel highcharts support replied:

...Default browser behavior is to block any content loaded from a domain that has CORS policy set up preventing requests from outside of the same domain.
This could be overridden by some CORS plugins, but the intention is to limit the data requests to our servers....

Hope this reply help others.